# What's iOS programming model of loading data from internet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading

My application needs to load some data from Internet when application starts up. Obviously it should load data in a thread, and show a progress bar/circle on UI, then after data loaded, hide the progress bar and update UI using the data.

Can anybody show me some code to archive that? Did apple provide such sample? It's my first time to use thread in iOS.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need multithreading to handle network communication without blocking your interface. What you need is asynchronous networking. This will also make your life a lot easier.

Have a look at [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/), which is a framework supporting seamless async communication.

[Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/) and [here](http://maniacdev.com/2012/07/using-afnetworkingjson-to-build-instagram-style-app-with-a-web-based-backend/), you can find tutorials about AFNetwoking integration in your project.